# Administrator Exchange Mailbox - Granting permissions

Tags: exchange-2007

I was wondering if there are any implications to delegating FullAccess rights to the actual Exchange administrator mailbox.  I'd like to be able to get messages destined for that account while I have my outlook/OWA open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you'll be fine...